# JSON Collection Issue

Tags: json

I have some json which looks like below (it is stored in a variable called json). I am trying to access the **last** json array value at this hierarchy - ***messages -> set_attributes -> row***. How can I do that thus far `json.messages[json.length].set_attributes.row` has not worked. I am using node.js

```
{  
   "messages":[  
      {  
         "set_attributes":{  
            "row":"13"
         },
         "title":"Jose Cuervo Gold",
         "image_url":"url",
         "subtitle":"$300 | tequila | 20",
         "buttons":[  
            {  
               "type":"show_block",
               "block_names":[  
                  "Add to Cart"
               ],
               "title":"Add to Cart"
            },
            {  
               "type":"show_block",
               "block_names":[  
                  "Add to Cart"
               ],
               "title":"More Info"
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "set_attributes":{  
            "row":"14"
         },
         "title":"Jose Cuervo Silver",
         "image_url":"url",
         "subtitle":"$250 | tequila | 30",
         "buttons":[  
            {  
               "type":"show_block",
               "block_names":[  
                  "Add to Cart"
               ],
               "title":"Add to Cart"
            },
            {  
               "type":"show_block",
               "block_names":[  
                  "Add to Cart"
               ],
               "title":"More Info"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Using what programming language…?

Comment: @deceze I am using nodejs

Answer (score 2):

Full answer would be

```
json.messages[json.messages.length-1].set_attributes.row
```

first of all array indexes start from 0 not from one, and second of all json is an object not an array, json.messages is the array you were looking for

Comment: When I try this I get the error Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: did you really name it json?

Answer (score 1):

The last json array is `[json.messages.length -1]` because an array start from 0 and not 1

Answer (score 0):

- You need to use **`json.messages.length`** instead of `json.length`. Because in your case, `json` is just a simple object, which won't return length.
- An *array index starts from 0*, you'll need to *take the **last index** as **`array.length - 1`***.

So, your code would be -

```
json.messages[json.messages.length - 1].set_attributes.row
```

> ***Suggestion*** for safe traversal -

```
json['messages'][json['messages']['length'] - 1]['set_attributes']['row']
```